# We have [size]d up this tag, and found it wanting

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request, clean-up

[size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) does not seem very useful when used alone, so the questions tagged with it should either be re-tagged (e.g. [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image)+[size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) renamed to [image-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-size)), or simply removed.

Comment: "Please don't use this tag in your posts - it's too generic to usefully categorise your question." ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir All the more reason to burn and ban it

Comment: Theres already image-size tag ;p

Comment: I can't see why `image-size` would be better than `size`? It is still too generic imo, it should be deleted all together.

Comment: @WouterJ: It's better because then we know someone's talking about an image, as opposed to the size of an executable, or the size of data in memory, any of which could be relevant to SO questions.

Comment: The tag has 6 followers. That tells you something. I would ask them. Or just get rid of it. I don't think it will be missed.

Comment: Thing is if you dont have a generic tag like size your always get people (0 rep users mostly) tag with things like `project-size`, `code-size`, `line-size`, because there is no size tag, or there just end up adding it anyway ;p I tend to check tags on every question I read and if it dont suit just remove it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler it's better than size, I agree. But assume size doesn't exists, there is no real sense in having a image-size tag. All size related tags zhould be burninated imo

Comment: So size really does matter...eek ;p

Comment: @MasonWheeler: "then we know someone's talking about an image, as opposed to the size of an executable"  [Hardly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx)